# Hyperbolic Riemannian Metric

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tangent-bundle

**Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory**, Chapter **9**, Page **277**, **278**.

According to the attached image (below) it seems that $v$ and $w$ should be of the form $v=(z,\alpha)$ and $w=(z,\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two complex number and $z\in \mathbb{H}$ ($z$ is also a complex number).

The questions are:

How is the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_z$ defined?

Is not it supposed to be a real inner product? (...dentos the usual inner product in $\mathbb{C}$ under the identification of ....).

> A convenient model for the hyperbolic plane is the upper half-plane
> $$\mathbb{H}=\{x+\mathrm{i}y\in\mathbb{C}\mid y>0\}$$
> with the hyperbolic metric. To define this metric, we need to introduce the tangent bundle* $\mathrm{T}\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{C}$ comprising the disjoint union of the tangent planes $\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}=\{z\}\times\mathbb{C}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{H}$. One should think of $\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}$ as a plane touching $\mathbb{H}$ tangentially at $z$ and having no other intersection with $\mathbb{H}$. This suggests that $\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}$ is the natural space for derivatives in the following sense. If $\phi:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{H}$ is differentiable at $t\in[0,1]$ with $\phi(t)=z$, then we define the derivative of $\phi$ at $t$ by
> $$\mathrm{D}\phi(t)=(\phi(t),\phi'(t))\in\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}.$$
>
> Here $\phi'(t)$ is the derivative of $\phi$ as a map into $\mathbb{C}$. We give $\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}$ the structure of a vector space inherited from the second component in $\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}=\{z\}\times\mathbb{C}$.
>
> The *hyperbolic Riemannian metric* is defined as the collection of inner products*
> $$\langle v,w\rangle_z=\frac{1}{y^2}(v\cdot w)$$
> for $z=x+\mathrm{i}y\in\mathbb{H}$ and $v,w\in\mathrm{T}_z\mathbb{H}$. Here $(v\cdot w)$ denotes the usual inner product in $\mathbb{C}$ under the identification of $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ as real vector spaces.
>
> The hyperbolic Riemannian metric induces the hyperbolic metric $\mathsf{d}(\cdot,\cdot)$ mentioned above as follows. If $\phi:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{H}$ is a continuous piecewise differentiable curve (we will refer to these as *paths*), then its length is defined by
> $$\mathrm{L}(\phi)=\int_0^1\|\mathrm{D}\phi(t)\|_{\phi(t)}\mathrm{d}t.$$
> where $\|\mathrm{D}\phi(t)\|_{\phi(t)}$ denotes the length of the tangent vector
> $$\mathrm{D}(\phi(t),\phi'(t))\in\mathrm{T}_{\phi(t)}\mathbb{H}$$
> with respect to the norm derived from $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\phi(t)}$. We will refer to as the *speed* of the path $\phi$ at time $t$. The hyperbolic distance is now defined as
> $$\mathsf{d}(z_0,z_1)=\inf_\phi\mathrm{L}(\phi)$$
> where the infimum is taken over all continuous piecewise differentiable curves $\phi$ with $\phi(0)=z_0$ and $\phi(1)=z_1$. It may be checked that this does indeed define a metric on $\mathbb{H}$.
>
> (*) The tangent bundle can be defined abstractly on any manifold, but for our purposes we may think of it as the space in which derivatives live and use an *ad hoc* definition.

I do appreciate any help could be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner product $\langle v,w\rangle_z$ for $v=(z,\alpha)$ and $w=(z,\beta)$ two tangent vectors in $T_z\mathbb{H}$ is defined as
$$
\langle v,w\rangle_z=\frac{\operatorname{Re}(\alpha\bar\beta)}{y^2}
$$
However, since we typically identify tangent spaces of a linear space $V$ with itself, we drop the $z$ and identify $v\in T_z\mathbb{H}$ with the complex number also called $v$ and similarly $w$ to get $v\cdot w=\operatorname{Re}(v\bar{w})$ instead of $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha\bar\beta)$.

Comment: I would add that, obviously, with these notations, $y = \mathrm{Im}z$.

Comment: Yeah, but $z=x+iy$ is right there on page 278 immediately under the first displayed equation.